# subclass contains a static member that base class uses

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++11 Is there some way I can define a static member variable in a subclass that is accessed by the (abstract) base class constructor? I've unsuccessfully tried messing with initialization lists, and tried setting a non-static base class pointer to that static subclass member. I'm starting to think I'll have to write a separate constructor for each subclass just so I can do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just pass that member as an argument to the base class constructor?

Comment: Did you try anything already?

Comment: The *Curiously Recurring Template Pattern* might help you, but you'll need to use an intermediate class template between your base class and your derived classes.

Comment: @Igor... OK, I was gone but I'm back now. GAHHH, you're so right. Quick, put that in an answer and I'll check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the subclass type to the base class as a template argument:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Derived>
struct Base
{
    Base()
    {
        std::cout << Derived::value << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Foo : Base<Foo>
{
    static const std::size_t value = 100;
};

struct Bar : Base<Bar>
{
    static const std::size_t value = 999;
};

int main()
{
    Foo baseFoo;
    Bar baseBar;
}
```

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4526e5395e150b8a)</kbd>